# Error when building z3 on unix: cannot find -lrt

Tags: z3

During make, I get an error with:

> g++ -o bin/external/z3 obj/external/act_cache.o : :
>   obj/external/smtlib_frontend.o obj/external/z3_log_frontend.o -lrt
>   -lpthread -fopenmp -static

The message is `/usr/lib/ ..... /i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt`

followed by similar messages about `-lpthread -lm -lc`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the `-static` option. See the following thread:
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/35135-cant-find-some-libraries.html

The new build system for Z3 does not use static libraries. If you are feeling adventurous, you can try the "unstable" branch which uses the new build system. Here are the instruction to build Z3 using it:

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/z3
cd z3
git checkout -b unstable
git pull origin unstable
autoconf
./configure
python scripts/mk_make.py
cd build
make

The git related commands can be replace with the .zip file downloaded from:
http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/946a06cddbe4
```

Comment: BTW, I submitted an update to the "unstable" branch. The new build system is more or less complete for Linux machines. The only thing missing is the ML bindings. It would be great if you could give a try.

Comment: Small update: I just compiled the "unstable" branch on `openSUSE-12.2-DVD-i586` (32-bit) and `linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-64bit`. I had to fix some additional compilation & linking problems. Here is the link for the updated branch http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/10b54d262e61.

Comment: After commenting out LDFLAGS_EXTRA=-static in Makefile z3 was successfully built.